# function with `message()` called during package startup - must use `packageStartupMessage()` for CRAN - but how?

Tags: r, message, startup

in my package [dmdScheme](https://github.com/UZH-PEG/dmdScheme/blob/7441e6fbc8807aa6343a982c22b80dfae7d079bd/R/aaa.R#L24) on CRAN in the line highlighted, I call a function with `message(...)`. This causes a warning on CRAN: https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-devel-linux-x86_64-fedora-clang/dmdScheme-00check.html.

How can I use the required `packageStartupMessage()` in this case? What are the side effects when using `packageStartupMessage()` instead of `message()` in the function, so that `packageStartupMessage()` is also called during the execution of the code after the startup?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: The reason for the requirement is that people want to be able to surpress startup messages without surpressing other messages.

Comment: If you don't want to modify your `scheme_install` function you could wrap the calls inside the `.onAttach` function inside `withCallingHandlers`, providing an appropriate `message` handler that first invokes `packageStartupMessage` and then invokes the `muffleMessage` restart. — But I would recommend instead modifying `scheme_install` so that it does not use `message` during package startup, by adding a suitable wrapper with an extra argument.

Comment: Thanks @KonradRudolph. I think I will go with the second approach (sounds easier), but instread of a parameter `quite`, I will add a parameter `startup` which uses `packageStartupMessage()` instead of `message()`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a package which has the same issue: in some cases, it will emit messages at package load time. The function that emits the message is sometimes called interactively, so it needs to call the regular `message()` function instead of `packageStartupMessage()`.

The package's `.onLoad()` function looks something like this:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  function_which_emits_message()
}
```

Wrapping it with this code converts the `message` to a `packageStartupMessage`:

```
withCallingHandlers(
  function_which_emits_message(),
  message = function(cnd) {
    packageStartupMessage(conditionMessage(cnd), appendLF = FALSE)
    tryInvokeRestart("muffleMessage")
  }
)
```